# Maintain separate rule files in drools

Tags: java, drools

I have a use-case where I need to maintain separate `drl` file for separate entities.
For example,
`entity 1` has a set of `facts` which should be driven by `drl1`
`entity 2` has a set of `facts` which should be driven by `drl2`

How should I implement this?

1. Load the drl's and corresponding facts in separate Knowledge base and sessions
2. Load all drl's and facts in single session.

I do not know how to achieve 2

Comment: What do you mean by entity? Some service API? Are you planning on using stateless or stateful session?

Comment: Are all rules - from drl1 and drl2 - to be evaluated at once? Then it's a single knowledge base and a single session. Otherwise it goes according to your #1. - "Entity" is the most nebulous term you might have used...

Comment: I think I should have used the word `domain` instead of `entity`

Comment: @laune drl1 and drl2 has no relation. They are to be applied on separate domains. Then can I load them to the same session?If so how will I ensure, drl1 is applied on domain 1

Comment: You have been asking how to achieve #2, which I've shown in my answer. If you don't want rules to be applied to facts, don't put them into a knowledge base from which the session is created. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your Knowledge Base along the lines given below, you can repeat adding another FileInputStream to the KieFileSystem.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
// repeat
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "simple/simple.drl" );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
// end
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();

Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
    System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
    throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
}
KieContainer kieContainer =
      kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```